# Rails 3, RSpec 2, and Cucumber yields wrong number of arguments (3 for 1) (ArgumentError)

Tags: rspec, cucumber, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I mostly followed these instructions to get things spun up:
http://lindsaar.net/2010/5/9/Getting-Rails-3-Edge-with-jQuery-RSpec-and-Cucumber-using-RVM

If I create a completely blank .feature file, running cucumber results in this error:

> cucumber
>
> wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)
>   (ArgumentError)
>   /gems/gherkin-2.0.2/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:125:in
>   `scan'
>   /gems/gherkin-2.0.2/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:125:in`
>   transition_table'
>   /gems/gherkin-2.0.2/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:112:in
>   `build_transition_map'
>   /gems/gherkin-2.0.2/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:108:in`
>   transition_map'
>   /gems/gherkin-2.0.2/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:75:in `initialize'
>   /gems/gherkin-2.0.2/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:52:in`new'
>   /gems/gherkin-2.0.2/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:52:in `push_machine'
>   /gems/gherkin-2.0.2/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:20:in`initialize'
>   /gems/cucumber-0.8.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/feature_file.rb:32:in
>   `new'
>   /gems/cucumber-0.8.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/feature_file.rb:32:in`
>   parse'
>   /gems/cucumber-0.8.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:62:in
>   `load_plain_text_features'
>   /gems/cucumber-0.8.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:60:in`
>   each'
>   /gems/cucumber-0.8.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:60:in
>   `load_plain_text_features'
>   /gems/cucumber-0.8.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:55:in`
>   execute!'
>   /gems/cucumber-0.8.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:25:in
>   `execute'
>   /gems/cucumber-0.8.3/bin/cucumber:8
>   /bin/cucumber:19:in`load'
>   /bin/cucumber:19

Interestingly, if I comment out the features/support/env.rb file, I do not get the error.  That doesn't do me much good though.  I can run the site successfully (It's empty).  Can anyone think of why the env code would kill the gherkin parser?  I'm a little too new at this to know where to look next.

Thanks.
-Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has this one answered for me.  It's an incompatibility between the latest cucumber and gherkin.  Needed to alter my gemfile to:

gem "cucumber"
  gem "gherkin", "= 2.1.4"
  gem "cucumber-rails"